# How to style this class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I added a  but I want to give it the same style as the other  components. The problem is that I don't know how to reference this class in my css. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: what is the name of the class?

Comment: The Logout commandLink that I've added.

Comment: Please next time don't post code as images

Comment: Image-only q & a are frowned on at S.O. Links go out of date, other's can't copy paste the code, they have to go outside the frame/editor to expand see your code, font/scale may not be what reviewers like or are used to, etc... Sometimes it may inhibit you from getting an answer or even slow it down. The negative votes to this question shows that a lot of people think it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that it's part of an unordered list (ul).
You can simply style it like this:

```
ul li {
  <what you want here>
}
```

Comment: No, it's getting the <a> style from my bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, simply this:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > form > a {
    ....
}
```